# Initialise a wix CheckBox's check state based on a property?

Tags: wix

How does one initalise a Wix check box based on the value of a property?

So far, I've done the following:

```
<Control Id="Checkbox" Type="CheckBox" X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="15" Property="CHECKBOX_SELECTION" Text="I want this feature" CheckBoxValue="1" TabSkip="no">
 <Condition Action="hide">HIDE_CHECKBOX</Condition>
  <Condition Action="show">NOT HIDE_CHECKBOX</Condition>
</Control>
```

Currently I have two custom actions to set HIDE_CHECKBOX and CHECKBOX_SELECTION. The CHECKBOX_SELECTION custom action occurs immediately after the HIDE_CHECKBOX action.

What I'm seeing is that HIDE_CHECKBOX is behaving correctly (ie. the checkbox is hidden) which suggests that I've got the ordering of custom actions correct, but CHECKBOX_SELECTION is not changing the check state of the check box. Is this a safe assumption? Also, I've confirmed that SELECTION is being set to '1' in the logs.

Am I on the right track? Have I misssd anything?

Comment: Hi, any chance you could post the action code as well?

Answer (score 0):

A snippet of the log showing the property changes would help a lot. Lacking that, I'll use my magic eight ball which noticed something that might just be a typo in your question but suggests:

Is it really the `SELECTION` Property that is getting marked to 1? If so that would not match the `CHECKBOX_SELECTION` Property the checkbox is based on and explain all the problems.